# Partition x does not start on physical sector boundary

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I recently partitioned a 2TB HDD with Gparted and have been using it for a few weeks without, i think, any problems (although see later).  But running fdisk -l i get the 'Partition x does not start on physical sector boundary' error, even though the partitions clearly do start on divisions of 2048.  I wonder if the problem is that the alighment offset is 3584 bytes.

Output below:

---

```
/$ sudo fdisk -l
```

[...]

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 3584 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5a94a8bc

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1             2048 3063111679 3063109632   1.4T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       3063111680 3907028991  843917312 402.4G 83 Linux

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

---

Ok so question is: do i need to fix this, and if so how.

Like i say the disk seems to be working fine *except* that i have noticed windows backup refuses to work on the NTFS partition, and the linux partition has on one occasion not mounted properly, although i was able to fix this with a fsck scan.

Comment: Is this a Seagate drive? Stange that this has exactly the same offset. https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/installing-linux-lite/partition-alignment-prompt-at-install/ Never have seen an alignment offset before, but really have not noticed it.

Comment: Yes, it's a seagate model ST32000540AS